# Databinding custom objects to controls in aspx file and not code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having issues fully binding a generic list in aspx file. Although It binds to my `<p>` and `<h>` tags properly but not my ImageButton. I'm I doing something wrong here. Below is my code

Aspx File

```
<%
int count = 1;
for (item = 0; item < mList.Count; AddItem())
{
   if (count == 3)
{ %>
<div class="one_third_last">
        <% count = 0;
            }
            else
            { %>
        <div class="one_third">
            <%}
            count++;%>
            <div class="modern_img_frame modern_four_col_large">
                <div class="preload_four_col_large">
                    <div class="attachment-fadeIn">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images2/premium-website-template-2.jpg"
                            ToolTip="CSS Template" AlternateText="CSS Template" Width="190" Height="111"
                            CommandName="<%# mList[item].PaymentCode %>" CommandArgument="<%# mList[item].PaymentDescription %>"
                            OnCommand="ImageButton_Command" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end modern_img_frame -->
            <h6>
                <%= mList[item].PaymentDescription%></h6>
            <p>
                <%= mList[item].PaymentDescription%></p>
        </div>
        <% 
}  %>
```

Code Behind

```
protected List<Payments_Default> mList;
protected int item;
public String PaymentCode { get; set; }
public String PaymentDescription { get; set; }
public int PaymentNumber { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       

    mList = new Payments_Default().GetPaymentTypes();
    this.DataBind();
}

protected void AddItem()
{
    item++;
}

protected List<Payments_Default> GetPaymentTypes()
{
    List<Payments_Default> mList = new List<Payments_Default>();
    Payments_Default mObject = null;

    SqlCommand command = GenericSqlDataAccess.CreateCommandOnline("Text");
    command.CommandText = "SELECT bla bla bla";

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = GenericSqlDataAccess.ExecuteReader(command);

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        mObject = new Payments_Default();
        mObject.PaymentCode = row["PayTypeCode"].ToString();
        mObject.PaymentDescription = row["PayTypeDesc"].ToString();
        mObject.PaymentNumber = table.Rows.Count;
        mList.Add(mObject);
    }

    return mList;
}
```

Comment: you are not data-binding, you are just adding some execution-code to the render-sequence ... properties of controls cannot be set via `<%=` (which just does the ol' `Response.Write`-alike-thing) rather with `<%#` which requires something like `repeater.DataSource = ...; repeater.DataBind();` = true data-binding ... read eg http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860/en

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but you can see i'm doing a check on the html mark-up to assign the appropriate css. How can i achieve that using a repeater?

Comment: there are various ways ... you can hook @ `DataItemBound` (event of Repeater) or any other appropriate event, or call a method (like `<%# this.GimmeCssClass((MyClass) Container.DataItem) %>`) or rethink your design in case you are using the `one_third_last` class for breaks - rather use some fluent stuff (eg float with fixed-width)... but recommending without knowing your explicit usage is very unrealistic, hence making such specific question very likely to be closed with "too specific" ...

Comment: btw, you can even mix data-binding with variables - which is *very* (!) ugly: introduce a (at least `protected`) class-variable eg `Counter` and in each `RepeaterItem` you do something like `class='<%# this.Counter++ == 3 ? "one_third_last" : "one_third" %>'` (be careful with quotes ...!) - but I would rather rethink the design before doing sth like that...